# Сортировка массива в обратном порядке

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка

Нужно отсортировать массив интов в обратном порядке.

Как `Arrays.sort(int[] a)`, только descending order.

Как это лучше сделать, чтобы самому вручную не писать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это будет так

```
sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)  // конструкция
```

Это как использовать

```
Arrays.sort(a, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Comment: спасибо, а я уже испугался, что нужно свой компаратор реализовывать)

Answer (score 1):

Стандартное api не дает возможности сортировать массив **примитивов** в обратном порядке, или даже переставить элементы массива задом наперед. Видимо разработчики решили, что хватит раздувать api на 9 методов под каждую операцию.

Можно перейти к `Integer[]` и сортировать его `Arrays.sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)` (через стримы можно сделать все сразу):

```
    final int[] ints = new int[] {4,3,6,3};
    Integer[] integers = Arrays.stream( ints ).boxed() // упаковка в Integer
        .sorted( Collections.reverseOrder() ) // сортировка
        .toArray( Integer[]::new ); // возврат массива

    int[] reverse = Arrays.stream( ints ).boxed()
        .sorted( Collections.reverseOrder() )
        .mapToInt( Integer::intValue ).toArray(); // если нужен обратно int[]
```

что ведет к созданию тучи объектов и потере производительности.

Можно перевернуть уже отсортированный массив (реализация из [Apache Commons Lang ArrayUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/)):

```
public static void reverse(int[] array) {
    if (array == null) {
        return;
    }
    int i = 0;
    int j = array.length - 1;
    int tmp;
    while (j > i) {
        tmp = array[j];
        array[j] = array[i];
        array[i] = tmp;
        j--;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Можно найти где-то библиотеку, умеющую сортировать массивы примитивов в нужном порядке: в [этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27095994) на enSO автор рекомендует свою библиотеку [Java Primitive](https://github.com/mintern-java/primitive#java-primitive). Или написать (или скопировать) свой метод сортировки.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы отсортировать массив в обратном порядке, по убыванию:

1. Массив примитивов `int[]`:

   ```java
   int[] arr1 = new int[]{0, 1, 2, 4, 3};
   int[] arr2 = Arrays.stream(arr1).boxed()
           .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
           .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
           .toArray();

   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr1)); // [0, 1, 2, 4, 3]
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2)); // [4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
   ```
2. Массив объектов `Integer[]`:

   ```java
   Integer[] arr = new Integer[]{0, 1, 2, 4, 3};

   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)); // [0, 1, 2, 4, 3]

   Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.reverseOrder());

   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)); // [4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
   ```

---

Чтобы развернуть массив по порядку вхождения элементов:

```java
int[] arr1 = new int[]{0, 1, 2, 4, 3};
int[] arr2 = IntStream.range(0, arr1.length)
        .map(i -> arr1[arr1.length - 1 - i])
        .toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr1)); // [0, 1, 2, 4, 3]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2)); // [3, 4, 2, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score -1):

Все очень просто в компораторе сортировки результат сравнения умножите на -1

```
return a.compareTo(b) * (-1); // умножаем на -1 для создания обратного порядка
```

Comment: Во-первых, проще поменять местами `a` и `b`. Во-вторых и это лишнее.