# Как отсортировать int[] со своим компаратором?

Tags: java, коллекции, generics

Массив `Integer`ов сортируется, а вот с массивом `int`ов что-то не получается:

https://ideone.com/tXfCql

```
class Ideone {
  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    Integer a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    int b[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    
    Arrays.sort(a, (x,y) -> y-x);
    //Arrays.sort(b, (x,y) -> y-x);
    
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
  }
}
```

Если раскомментировать сортировку массива `b`, то будет ошибка

```
Main.java:11: error: no suitable method found for sort(int[],(x,y)->y - x)
    Arrays.sort(b, (x,y) -> y-x);
          ^
    method Arrays.<T#1>sort(T#1[],Comparator<? super T#1>) is not applicable
      (inference variable T#1 has incompatible bounds
        equality constraints: int
        upper bounds: Object)
    method Arrays.<T#2>sort(T#2[],int,int,Comparator<? super T#2>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#2
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1>sort(T#1[],Comparator<? super T#1>)
    T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>sort(T#2[],int,int,Comparator<? super T#2>)
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error
```

Как его правильно отсортировать с кастомным компаратором?

Comment: Оффтоп: `y-x` может привести к переполнению. Лучше использовать `Integer.compare(y,x)` или, по ситуации, `Collections.reverseOrder`

Comment: @defaultlocale, про переполнение [я в курсе](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/432370/178988), просто привёл самый компактный компаратор в качестве примера :)

Comment: @katso, а зачем import'ы удалил?

Comment: @Qwertiy, в данном случае без них лаконичнее, а смысловой нагрузки они не несут.

Comment: @katso, я несколько не согласен с этой позицией: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4239/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy, а я в корне не согласен с вашей позицией, очень сложно вычитывать код, где по 40 строк импорта. всегда редактирую такие вопросы.

Comment: @katso, если не интересны import'ы, надо просто не читать кусок до первой пустой строки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Массив `Integer`ов сортируется, а вот с массивом `int`ов что-то не получается

И правильно, что не получается, так как дженерики (коим является `Comparator<T>`) не параметризуются примитивами, а автобоксинг для массивов не работает.

> Как отсортировать `int[]` со своим компаратором?

Так, как хотите Вы (непосредственно с помощью `Arrays.sort(...)`) -- никак, но есть множество альтернативных решений, которые перечислены в [соседнем ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/733311/220996).

Comment: @defaultlocale, Ваша правда. Updated.

Comment: А? Зачем удалил кусок ответа?

Comment: @Qwertiy, Некорректный код был.

Answer (score 3):

Не знаю, подойдёт ли вам такое решение, но в Java 8 можно так:

```
b = IntStream.of(b)
    .boxed()
    .sorted((x,y) -> y-x)
    .mapToInt(i -> i)
    .toArray();
```

С помощью [Java Primitive](https://github.com/mintern-java/primitive#java-primitive) можно так:

```
Primitive.sort(b, (x, y) -> Integer.compare(y, x), false);
```

Подключать так:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>net.mintern</groupId>
   <artifactId>primitive</artifactId>
   <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

С [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) так:

```
Collections.sort(Ints.asList(b), (x,y) -> y-x);
```

Подключать так:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>23.2-jre</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Похоже метод с лямбдой использует дженерик, попробуйте написать анонимный класс.
Если пользуетесь идеей, то может она подскажет как переделать в лямбду

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае вызывается метод [`Arrays.sort(T[],Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator)), который ожидает массив объектов `T[]`, а не массив примитивов `int[]`. Для сортировки массива примитивов своим компаратором, нужно сперва привести элементы массива к объектному типу, затем сортировать:

```java
int[] arr1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

int[] arr2 = Arrays.stream(arr1)
        // упаковываем int в Integer
        .boxed()
        // сортируем
        .sorted((x, y) -> y - x)
        // распаковываем обратно
        .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
        // собираем в массив
        .toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr1)); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2)); // [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

---

См. дополнительно:

- [Сортировка массива в обратном порядке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1217356/420361)
- [Какие существуют способы инверсии массива в Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1217093/420361)